# Broken links in PhantomJS

Tags: asp.net, phantomjs

I use PhantomJS for my project.
Seems that the links generated by the server are wrong. they look very strange.
I've got this from the output of Process.StandardError:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
>
> `http://localhost/MyWebsite/AppName/(F(nwmx6eY2n1ZH2wmw2Wsta6X7s6OIeQ8LLQxbeJ5uULf99WBNZ12KatxFMKam4Vr9r1fUrkDLc8t5XvaR9EcW67kkaZB32ftWPOH-GvvuUaIKJZMtBcMYjIY3---ewwTEsXVZl6MfNOZQIwRBahBG-xtBrzvW2tdh4TM9CSU8c467zudg0))/Page.aspx:424`
>   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
>
> `http://localhost/MyWebsite/AppName/(F(nwmx6eY2n1ZH2wmw2Wsta6X7s6OIeQ8LLQxbeJ5uULf99WBNZ12KatxFMKam4Vr9r1fUrkDLc8t5XvaR9EcW67kkaZB32ftWPOH-GvvuUaIKJZMtBcMYjIY3---ewwTEsXVZl6MfNOZQIwRBahBG-xtBrzvW2tdh4TM9CSU8c467zudg0))/Page.aspx:804`
>   TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating
>   'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager')
>
> `http://localhost/MyWebsite/AppName/(F(nwmx6eY2n1ZH2wmw2Wsta6X7s6OIeQ8LLQxbeJ5uULf99WBNZ12KatxFMKam4Vr9r1fUrkDLc8t5XvaR9EcW67kkaZB32ftWPOH-GvvuUaIKJZMtBcMYjIY3---ewwTEsXVZl6MfNOZQIwRBahBG-xtBrzvW2tdh4TM9CSU8c467zudg0))/Page.aspx:890`

That's why jQuery couldn't be loaded.
Anyone has an idea why this happens? In Chrome it looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, seems that the problem in the way ASP.Net recognizes the browser and browser definitions settings. And to make phantom.js work I added phantomjs.browser file in App_Browsers folder with the following code:

```
<browsers>
  <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.0 Safari/534.34 -->
  <browser id="PhantomJS" parentID="Safari">
    <identification>
      <userAgent match="PhantomJS/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)\w*)" />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
      <capability name="browser"                         value="PhantomJS" />
      <capability name="majorversion"                    value="${major}" />
      <capability name="minorversion"                    value="${minor}" />
      <capability name="type"                            value="PhantomJS${major}" />
      <capability name="version"                         value="${version}" />
      <capability name="ecmascriptversion"               value="3.0" />
      <capability name="javascript"                      value="true" />
      <capability name="javascriptversion"               value="1.7" />
      <capability name="w3cdomversion"                   value="1.0" />
      <capability name="supportsAccesskeyAttribute"      value="true" />
      <capability name="tagwriter"                       value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
      <capability name="cookies"                         value="true" />
      <capability name="frames"                          value="true" />
      <capability name="javaapplets"                     value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsCallback"                value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsDivNoWrap"               value="false" />
      <capability name="supportsFileUpload"              value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"                 value="true" />
      <capability name="tables"                          value="true" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

It tells the server to use cookies with Phantom.JS as a browser:

```
<capability name="cookies" value="true" />
```

And this way the links are generated correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is due to ASP not recognizing the user agent and using "Craazy String!" instead of cookies.

If you can't edit App_Browsers, or don't want to, just set your user-agent in phantomjs to an exact string from a browser known to work.

Example:

```
var page = new WebPage();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.36 Safari/537.36'
```

or, in casperjs:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
pageSettings: {
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.36 Safari/537.36'
}
});
```